# Can I use an extension method with a Structure in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, json, serialization

I am wondering whether I can use DataContractJsonSerializer to serialize a Structure type, or does it have to be a reference/Class type?

I have the following code:

```
<Extension()> Public Function ToJSON(ByVal target As Object) As String
    Dim serializer = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(target.GetType)
    Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, target)
        ms.Flush()

        Dim bytes As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()

        Dim json As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length).Trim(Chr(0))

        Return json
    End Using
End Function
```

And yet if I call it on a Structure type, such as a KeyValuePair(Of T1, T2), I get the following error:

> Public member 'ToJSON' on type 'KeyValuePair(Of String,Object)' not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message does not have anything to do with `DataContractJsonSerializer` or anything inside your method. It cannot find the method itself. That suggests to me that you have forgotten to add a reference to the namespace in which this extension method is defined. I apologise I don’t know the VB equivalent, but in C# it is the `using` clause I’m talking about.

Comment: Hmm... odd. You are correct, that was the problem. This did teach me something else I didn't realize though. The extension was a public function in a public module in a DLL. I had the DLL/namespace imported to my aspx.vb file by means of an `Import` statement at the top of the file, and I was getting this error. I added the same import as a `\system.web\pages\namespaces` import in the web.config and then it worked fine. Apparently in ASP.NET you need to import your namepaces via web.config, NOT via Import statements in the VB file? Odd.